# Rails saving without Savepoint (directly commit save/create)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to know if there's any way I can insert into Rails through ActiveRecord without going through savepoint. So, directly insert (and commit).

The problem is that, if there's exception being thrown, I don't want a save/create being within the same transaction to also be rolledback. I tried several hours looking for it but unsure how.

My database in development is SQLite, I believe there's should be anything sparklingly different in saving.

EDIT: Code

```
  log = config.model.where(md5: md5).first
  if log
    puts "I AM HERE 5A"
    log.frequency += 1
    log.save
  else
    puts "I AM HERE 5B"
    config.model.transaction(requires_new: true) do
      config.model.create!({
         md5: md5,
         level: level,
         message: message,
         backtrace: backtrace,
         class_name: class_name,
         method_name: options[:method],
         line: options[:line],
         file_name: options[:file],
         parameters: (options[:parameters].blank? ? "" : options[:parameters].inspect),
         description: options[:description]
      })

    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you show us some code as an example of what you'd like (use "magic_save_without_savepoint" for the method you'd like to exist if you must) ;)

Comment: nothing fancy really, just .create. But sometimes exception is thrown because of Timeout may be, and that I don't want my data to be rolledback.

Comment: For us to help you... we need to actually see it. Your verbal description is clear inside your head... but not in ours ;)

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, You have to save record although there is any validation error.

Try use `Model.save(:validate => false)` this will save your record although you get any validation error while saving record.

Comment: there's no validation error, but exception may be raise and it has nothing to do with validation.